# Run a script as soon as a USB is plugged

Tags: windows, usb

Is there any way to run a script from a USB as soon as I plug it in (on Windows),
even when the auto-run feature is disabled? 
so that no matter to which computer I plug the USB it will execute the script
(like hackers in the movies do)

Comment: Let's hope not.

Comment: This question gets asked a *lot* but I can't seem to find any exact duplicates.  How about we leave this one open so the others can all be marked as duplicates pointing here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, autorun is a major security issue that was fixed several versions ago by Microsoft.  It was a handy feature to have when you wanted to install software from a CD in 1995, but it's too dangerous for today's world.

If you have control over the firmware of the USB device, you might try emulating an HID keyboard and taking control of the user's computer that way.  See [BadUSB](https://nakedsecurity.sophos.com/2014/08/02/badusb-what-if-you-could-never-trust-a-usb-device-again/) and [USB Rubber Ducky](https://hakshop.com/products/usb-rubber-ducky-deluxe).